# Unable to list out my site's soap services with error (XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document)

Tags: api, magento2.3.2, soap

I am trying to list my Magento 2.3.2 site's soap API by running to below URL,
https://mysiteurl/index.php/soap/default?wsdl_list=1

However, it only shows the error message below

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I have also try to access my soap api url and get a named default file as below with a empty row on the first row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" >
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <env:Code>
            <env:Value>env:Receiver</env:Value>
         </env:Code>
         <env:Reason>
            <env:Text xml:lang="en">Invalid XML</env:Text>
         </env:Reason>
         
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I am not sure whether the first empty row causes the error. If yes, how do I remove the empty row?  Many thanks!

Comment: yes the issue is the first empty row just remove it

Answer (score 0):

just moved the xml declaration at the top of the page and it will solve your issue. let me know if this does not work for you i have another fix for this but this one is the easiest and most common so first give it a shot.

**Hope this helps**

Comment: Thank you! But I do not have any idea how to remove the first empty row as the file is downloaded when I access the api url. I don't know how the file is generated.

Comment: dude just check for xml file that has space on top just remove that space

Comment: Do you have any idea for the xml file. I have checked all the xml file which I created but does not have any space on the top. 
For your information, I get the file by accessing this url: https://mysiteurl/soap/default? .

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/soap/bk-soap.html